# How to put progress bar around the edge of the screen in Wear OS

Tags: android, xml, wear-os

guys I am trying to make my progress bar around the edge of the screen but it's not happening even tho i put both width and height to match_parent still it's sitting in the centre not on the edges.

Here is my progress bar code

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pgMeasurement"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Large"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[image: here are the end results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xml code I use:

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
```

The drawable file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="270"
    android:toDegrees="270">

    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.02"
        android:thickness="2px"
        android:useLevel="true">

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Comment: Hi, now I can see the progress bar around the edges with some edits, but now my question is how to animate it ? as it's static not moving in circles like regular progress bar was doing before. Thanks :)